# Threejs BufferGeomatry raycast not hitting

Tags: node.js, three.js, raycasting

I'm creating a subdivided plane buffer geometry to improve performance from the plain plane geometry, but my raycast isn't hitting the PlaneBufferGeometry.

I'm getting this error in the console that I think it probably the issue:

```
THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): 
Computed radius is NaN. The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values.
```

My code for creating the buffered geometry is:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(maxs['ROW'], maxs['COL'], maxs['ROW'] / 4, maxs['COL'] / 4);

var floor = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, floorMaterial);

floor.rotation.x = -(Math.PI / 2);
floor.position.y = y;
```

I'm using the latest version of ThreeJS from the npm package.

Could you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong? Since ThreeJS is minified I'm not able to really look through the code to find why it's thrown.

Comment: Make sure the last 2 values you're passing to `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry` are integers... `parseInt( maxs['ROW'] / 4 ), parseInt( maxs['COL'] / 4 )`.

Comment: @mrdoob that did it! weird, I though they where already ints. Please change your comment to an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the last 2 values you're passing to `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry` are integers... `parseInt( maxs['ROW'] / 4 ), parseInt( maxs['COL'] / 4 )`.

Comment: `parseInt( ... ,10)` is even better